# How to change the direction of nav items from ltr to rtl?

Tags: javascript, html, css, twitter-bootstrap, angular-ui-bootstrap

I have the following code of bootstrap and need to change the direction of items in the nav to be right-to-left instead of left-to-right (to make item 1 the first from right) without using the bootstrap-rtl , I also try to use direction:rtl in the ul but didn't work.

as a conclusion I need this shape
[image]
any help please?

```
<nav class="navbar navbar-default navbar-fixed-top" role="navigation">
    <div class="container">
        <!-- Brand and toggle get grouped for better mobile display -->
        <div class="logo"><a href="#"><img src="img/logob.png" alt=""></a></div>
        <div class="navbar-header">
            <button type="button" class="navbar-toggle fl7" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#bs-example-navbar-collapse-1">
                <span class="sr-only">Toggle navigation</span>
                <span class="icon-bar"></span>
                <span class="icon-bar"></span>
                <span class="icon-bar"></span>
            </button>

        </div>
        <!-- Collect the nav links, forms, and other content for toggling -->
        <div class="collapse navbar-collapse" id="bs-example-navbar-collapse-1">
            <ul class="nav navbar-nav">
                <li><a href="#">item 1</a></li>
                <li><a href="#">item 2</a></li>
                <li><a href="#">item 3</a></li>
                <li><a href="#">item 4</a></li>
                <li><a href="#">item 5</a></li>
            </ul>
        </div>
        <!-- /.navbar-collapse -->
    </div>
    <!-- /.container -->
</nav>
```

Comment: can you please demonstrate it on JSFiddle?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

If you float your `li` elements to the right, they will be in reverse order. See snippet.

```css
.nav.navbar-nav {
  list-style-type: none;
  display: inline-block;
  padding: 0;
  margin: 0;
}

.nav.navbar-nav li {
  float: right;
  margin-right: 10px;
}

@media (min-width: 768px) { 
  .nav.navbar-nav {
    color: red;
  }
}
```

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css">
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
  <script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
<nav class="navbar navbar-default navbar-fixed-top" role="navigation">
  <div class="container">
    <!-- Brand and toggle get grouped for better mobile display -->
    <div class="logo">
      <a href="#"><img src="img/logob.png" alt=""></a>
    </div>
    <div class="navbar-header">
      <button type="button" class="navbar-toggle fl7" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#bs-example-navbar-collapse-1">
                <span class="sr-only">Toggle navigation</span>
                <span class="icon-bar"></span>
                <span class="icon-bar"></span>
                <span class="icon-bar"></span>
            </button>

    </div>
    <!-- Collect the nav links, forms, and other content for toggling -->
    <div class="collapse navbar-collapse" id="bs-example-navbar-collapse-1">
      <ul class="nav navbar-nav">
        <li><a href="#">item 1</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">item 2</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">item 3</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">item 4</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">item 5</a></li>
      </ul>
    </div>
    <!-- /.navbar-collapse -->
  </div>
  <!-- /.container -->
</nav>
```

You can use media queries to have different behaviors for desktop/mobile. [See this jsfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/h6knvtxk/).

Comment: It work well and sorted as I want, but the menu appears linear in the mobile view! I don't want that, I want it as usual to be listed virtically

Comment: So you want it in reverse order but vertical?

Comment: in normal view (laptop) I want it as your code exactly (rtl), and to be listed vertically in mobile view (starting with item 1 from top)

Comment: You should look into media queries then. That way you can have different styles for different device sizes.

Comment: I added a picture above, see it please

Comment: @Maria Rod if this answer helped you, please accept it otherwise it would attract spam answers. This is how SO works.

Comment: Thanks a lot, it works well, but I'm new here, I accepted it.

Answer (score -1):

try using float ul.
css - ul{float:right}

Comment: If you float the whole `ul` to the right it will not reverse the items in the list.